# QGIS doesn't render raster alpha channel properly (jagged edges)

Tags: qgis, raster

I have two rasters in my project clipped by custom mask and translated to jpg. One is perfectly fine, but the other one has jagged edges which appear right after translating & saving to jpg. Photoshop sees both rasters correctly, but QGIS renders only one properly, while the other one has those saw-like edges. I tried other source rasters, other masks, other QGIS versions and nothing works, besides saving to tiff. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]